# Transfering class from an activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Im trying to use viewPager so I want to change my class from an activity to fragment, but Im getting alot of errors, so can you tell me whats wrong and what I need to do?

Here is my original activity :

```
    package com.pickapp.pachu.pickapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private TitlesDB titles;
    private Button getPickUpLine;
    private TextView pickUpLine;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
        titles = new TitlesDB(this);
        initDB();
        initialize();
    }

    public void initialize() {
        this.getPickUpLine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGetLine);
        this.getPickUpLine.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.pickUpLine = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLine);
        this.pickUpLine.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void initDB() {
        titles.open();
        if (!this.titles.isExist()) {
            titles.createEntry("The I \n Have Cancer");
            titles.createEntry("The Ocean");
        }
        titles.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.bGetLine:
                titles.open();
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int index = rnd.nextInt(titles.getLength()) + 1;
                pickUpLine.setText(titles.getTitleById(index));
                titles.close();
                break;
            case R.id.tvLine:
                if(!pickUpLine.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    Intent intent  = new Intent(this, PickAppLine.class);
                    intent.putExtra("key", pickUpLine.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I tried :

```
    package com.pickapp.pachu.pickapp;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    /**
     * Created by Golan on 19/08/2014.
     */
    public class MainScreenFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

        private TitlesDB titles;
        private Button getPickUpLine;
        private TextView pickUpLine;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            titles = new TitlesDB(getActivity());
            initDB();
            View v = getView();
            initialize(v);
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_screen, container, false);
        }

        public void initialize(View v) {
            this.getPickUpLine = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.bGetLine);
            this.getPickUpLine.setOnClickListener(this);
            this.pickUpLine = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvLine);
            this.pickUpLine.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void initDB() {
            titles.open();
            if (!this.titles.isExist()) {
                titles.createEntry("The I \n Have Cancer");
                titles.createEntry("The Ocean");
            }
            titles.close();
        }

        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.bGetLine:
                titles.open();
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int index = rnd.nextInt(titles.getLength()) + 1;
                pickUpLine.setText(titles.getTitleById(index));
                titles.close();
                break;
            case R.id.tvLine:
                if(!pickUpLine.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    Intent intent  = new Intent(this, PickAppLine.class);
                    intent.putExtra("key", pickUpLine.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: I thought you're using an IDE such as Android Studio or Eclipse so that if you're making a mistake, it yells at you and tells you exactly what your mistake is (logcat, compiler errors, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

We won't just fix all your code. You have to do that yourself! Remove everything that you don't need at the beginning and start adding one after the other again. Fix all the errors on the way. It is hard to know what the actual problem is when everything is wrong.

One thing that I see right away that definitely does not work is this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_screen, container, false); // NO, NO, NO!!

    titles = new TitlesDB(getActivity());
    initDB();
    initialize();
}
```

You have a return statement in the method BEFORE you have more code. That can not work. The return statement has to be at the end!

Comment: You can ask again here if you have a specific error that you cannot fix yourself.

Comment: Yeah I realized that and everything is fine now, but how do I pass the data between 2 fragments? because that is the problem now and I have no idea how to replace this :
Intent intent  = new Intent(this, PickAppLine.class);
                    intent.putExtra("key", pickUpLine.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(intent);

Comment: You only show us one Fragment above and no point where you want to pass any data from one to another. Your above code will still not work btw because `getView()` will return `null` at this point. Pass the `View` as a parameter to the `initialize()` method.

Comment: Alright, I changed the code, please tell me if the view thing is fixed now, and I want to pass the string name from the MainScreenFragment to a different Activity, in the code there is the way to pass data between activities, how do I change it? - Thank You!

Comment: Nope, the View problem is not fixed. You are calling `getView()` before you actually inflate it. YOU inflate the View in `onCreateView()` and return it to the `Fragment`. Only after that happened `getView()` can return something. `View v = inflater.inflate(...); initialize(v); return v;`.

Comment: Your `Activity` probably holds an instance of the `Fragment`, since it adds it. So why not just add a getter method to the Fragment and then the `Activity` can get the value whenever it wants? Or check here, there are some infos that might help you: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html